# Change date to next trading date

Tags: python-3.x, date

I have two tables:

```
-event dates
-return dates
```

Some event dates are not at a trading day.

How can I change the event date to the next trading day? 
So if event date is not in return dates, take the next day in return dates.

The approach to change weekend days to working days does not work because of days like Christmas. 
The best would be to look up the next day in the return table.

```
for i in event['date']: 
      if i is not in return ['date'].values: 
            event ['date']=i+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

but this doenst work

I am working with dataframes and dates have the format datetime64[ns]. If the event date does not exist in return date than event date plus one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

After the clarifications concerning the desired logic, here is the new solution

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create two df
event_date = datetime.now()
event_dates = pd.DataFrame([datetime(2020, 2, _) for _ in range(1, 29)], columns=['date'])
print(event_dates.date[0])
# 2020-02-01 00:00:00
return_dates = pd.DataFrame([datetime(2020, 1, _) for _ in range(1, 32)], columns=['date'])

# Apply logic
event_dates.date = [_ if _ in return_dates.date else _ + timedelta(days=1) for _ in event_dates.date]
print(event_dates.date[0])
# 2020-02-02 00:00:00
```

---

## Base Python

Here is a solution using the standard `datetime` library

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List


def get_next_trade_date(date: datetime, date_list: List[datetime]) -> datetime:  # The annotations here are just to specify the types of the objects
    if date in date_list:  # Check if the date is contained in the list
        return date
    delta, res = None, None  # Initialize both to None
    for _ in date_list:
        tmp = abs((date - _).days)  # Time difference in current iteration
        if not delta or tmp < delta:  # See bullet point 1.
            delta, res = tmp, _
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_date = datetime.now()
    return_dates = [datetime(2020, 1, _) for _ in range(1, 32)]
    print(get_next_trade_date(event_date, return_dates))
    # 2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Notice that

1. The condition `not delta or tmp < delta` is twofold: in the *first* iteration `delta, res` are both `None` so we will overwrite them with `tmp, _`. We catch this by using `not delta`. The other part (`tmp < delta`) is more obvious: if we have a new minimal delta then we overwrite `delta, res`.
2. I only considered days intervals (`(date - _).days`), you could go further into details (see `datetime.timedelta` for more info)
3. coming from `R` I believe there must be a simpler solution using `numpy` - see below

## Numpy

This solution uses `numpy`. `(date_list - date)` is an array of timedeltas,  `(date_list - date).argmin()` returns the *index* of the minimal value.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np


def get_next_trade_date(date: datetime, date_list: np.ndarray) -> datetime:
    return date_list[(date_list - date).argmin()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_date = datetime.now()
    return_dates = np.array([datetime(2020, 1, _) for _ in range(1, 32)])
    print(get_next_trade_date(event_date, return_dates))
    # 2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: it looks very difficult for me. Do you know  a solution like: if date is not in return ['dates'] than change column value to date + 1 oneday

Comment: for i in event['date']:
    if i is not in return ['date'].values:
        event ['date']=i+datetime.timedelta(days=1), but this doenst work

Comment: @pythoo I some comments explaining the first solution and also a second solution using `numpy`. It looks as if you're working with data frames or dictionaries. I have two question: 1. Could you edit your question and share a sample of the data? 2. What logic do you want to apply? (a. `if date in return_dates --> date else closest match in return_dates` or b. `f date in return_dates --> date else date + 1` ?)

Comment: logic b. both tables are dataframes and have one column with date.